# Rails mountable engines helper methods not found when routing from main app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-engines

I have a module as a mountable engine mounted to a main app 
through

```
mount MyEngine::Engine, :at => '/myengine'
```

I have everything namespaced in the negine and the engine has it's own views in engine/app/views/myengine/

Everything works fine when I run rails server then try to access

> localhost:3000/myengine

first then go to the root of the main app and come back to the engine through a link in the index view of the main app

However when I start the server, go to localhost:3000 and from there click on the link to the engine module it tries to fetch the views correctly however the methods contained in the engine's helpers raises an error upon call for them being undefined.

I am on rails 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used eager_load to load the mountable engine in it's initialized in the main app and everything seems to be working now.

`Myengine::Engine.eager_load!`

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue as well. I had defined an `ApplicationController` inside my engine and was seeing `NoMethodError`s when I tried to use helper methods inside one of my engine's controllers.

#### The Problem

The code looked something like this:

in my_engine/app/controllers/my_engine/application_controller.rb

```
module MyEngine
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    helper ApplicationHelper
  end
end
```

in my_engine/app/controllers/my_engine/projects_controller.rb

```
module MyEngine
  class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
    def new
      # some action code here
    end
  end
end
```

in my_engine/app/helpers/my_engine/application_helper.rb

```
module MyEngine
  module ApplicationHelper
    def translations_include_tag
      javascript_include_tag "translations-#{I18n.locale}.js"
    end
  end
end
```

If I navigated to a route in the host rails app, then clicked a link that navigated to my_engine/projects/new, I would get a `NoMethodError` saying `translations_include_tag` didn't exist.

#### The Explanation

I think this was happening because the application had two classes with the same name: `ApplicationController` in `MyEngine` and `ApplicationController` in the host app. When the first route outside the engine is visited, Rails autoloads the `ApplicationController` from the host app. What that means is Rails associates the main app's `ApplicationController` with the name "ApplicationController". When you navigate to my_engine/projects/new, Rails lazy loads `ProjectsController` which also inherits from `ApplicationController`. Rails/ruby thinks you're referring to the *same* `ApplicationController` it has already loaded, so in effect `ProjectsController` ends up inheriting from the host app's `ApplicationController` instead of the one in the engine. Since the `translations_include_tag` method isn't defined in the host app's `ApplicationController`, ruby raises a `NoMethodError` when the view tries to call it.

#### The Solution

I was able to fix the problem by explicitly inheriting from `MyEngine`'s `ApplicationController`:

in my_engine/app/controllers/my_engine/projects_controller.rb

```
module MyEngine
  # changed from just plain 'ol ApplicationController
  class ProjectsController < ::MyEngine::ApplicationController
    def new
      # some action code here
    end
  end
end
```

After fixing the inheritance issue, the `NoMethodError` went away.

The accepted answer says to use eager loading, which will also fix the problem because it forces the engine's `ApplicationController` to load first. Since the engine's `ApplicationController` is namespaced inside `MyEngine`, it's full name is MyEngine::ApplicationController, which doesn't conflict with the main app's `ApplicationController` because the constant names are different.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the helpers explicitely in your `lib/engine.rb` file:

```
initializer 'your-gem-name.setup_helpers' do |app|
    app.config.to_prepare do
      ActionController::Base.send :include, HelperModuleName
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Same problem, I also would like to stress on that the problem only occurs when I try to access the module after first access the main app however when I access the module first everything appears to be normal after that and I can navigate correctly.

Comment: is there a chance that there is some module of the same name in your app?

Comment: no there is no other module with the same name or close to it